# iTextSharp irregular placement of TextField along Y-axis

Tags: c#, windows, itext

I am using iTextSharp to draw TextField in PDF files. Please look into code I am using to draw TextField:

```
//getting pdf file from the Temp folder
string p_FileName1 = Path.GetTempFileName();

//Pdf Reader reading the file
TextSharp.PdfReader rdr = new TextSharp.PdfReader(p_FileName);

//Initialize the PdfStamper 
TextSharp.PdfStamper stamper = new TextSharp.PdfStamper(rdr,File.Create(p_FileName1));

//here is calculating the point position of the Area drawn for the Textboxes to be displayed
float pointX1 = Global.Percent(item.TextBoxInfoList[i].point.Point.X, 1.0f, Convert.ToSingle(page.Width.Point)) + 12;

float pointY1 = Global.Percent(item.TextBoxInfoList[i].point.Point.Y, 1.0f, Convert.ToSingle(page.Height.Point)) + 12;

float pointX2 = Global.Percent(item.TextBoxInfoList[i].po2.X, 1.0f, Convert.ToSingle(page.Width.Point)) + 12;

float pointY2 = Global.Percent(item.TextBoxInfoList[i].po2.Y, 1.0f, Convert.ToSingle(page.Height.Point)) + 12;

float tw = pointX2 - pointX1;
float th = pointY2 - pointY1;

pointY1 = Convert.ToSingle(page.Height.Point) - pointY2;

System.util.RectangleJ rec;
//-- Position 5 point so that it will align with the requirement.                           
rec = new System.util.RectangleJ((pointX1 -5), pointY1, tw, th);

TextSharp.TextField tf = new TextSharp.TextField(stamper.Writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(rec), fieldname);

stamper.FormFlattening = true; 

stamper.AddAnnotation(tf.GetTextField(), pageNumber + 1);
```

Below is my Percent function used to find position of TextDrawn

```
public static float Percent(float complete, float total, float max)
{
    if (complete == 0.0f || total == 0.0f) return 0.0f;

        return (complete / total) * max;
}
```

This is code is working fine for me, except I am getting issue of placement of Textfield in Y-axis. Sometimes it is drawn at the point where points are drawn and expected. But most of the time, it gives issue with placement in Y-axis and drawn below or above the expected position. This happens with different PDF files used. Please let me know if any further clarification on the code from my end is required.

Comment: Please illustrate your problems more clearly, E.g. supply a sample input PDF, the associated result PDF, the input values your code works with in that case, and give a sketch of how the result differs from your expectations.

Comment: Your question needs some clarification. You refer to "points" (*where points are drawn*): what are they? What are `page.Width.Point`, `page.Height.Point` and `item.TextBoxInfoList[i]`. Just sample values are probably fine.

Comment: page.Width.Point = 595.276,page.Height.Point = 841.89,it contain number of TextField that i want to drawn.currently it contain reference to  public List<TextBoxU> TextBoxInfoList;

Comment: it gives the issue of drawing Textfield on different PDF files used ,minor in Y-Axis

Comment: ,please check the image for more clarification
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mxelrkl28450eaf/PDF%20Issue.png?dl=0